# Swift set margins to the left and right side at TableViewCells

Tags: swift, uitableview, margins

I want a TableView like that one:
[image]

With a margin on the left and right side and cornered border at top and bottom.
Nothing works for me.
I want to set it in a TableViewController.
My code for the cell definition:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.row]

    cell.label.text = categories[indexPath.row]

    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    return cell
}
```

My TableView now:
[image]

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. Correct me if I'm wrong, I believe the TableView look that this is using is the `Grouped` Style. Sorry if I completely didn't understand your question.

[image: Check out the screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a tableView that corresponds to the image you can do the following:

Instead setting the left and right margin to the tableViewCell, set it on the tableView.( Do it programatically or in the interface builder)

```
tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
```

And set the rounded corner

```
// Change cornerRadius according your needs
tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
tableView.clipsToBounds = true
```